# Reunion of Lakshmi and Vishnu after Soma's Rajasuya

Tags: vishnu, lakshmi, matsya-purana, soma

Chapter 23 of Matsya Purana tells that after the completion of Soma's Rajasuya nine devis abandoned their husbands due to kama and served Soma( who in turn desired them like his own wives). Among them was Lakshmi who abandoned Narayana.

As per the story of Vekateshwara they might have reunioned somehow after this incident. *Is their any story that describe their union after this incident?* Or if this incident might happened in some other kalpa, did Vishnu remained wifeless for the remaining of that particular kalpa?